# Combine two mono mics into one stereo signal, such that each mic gets its own channel (left and right)

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, stereo, portable-recorder, mono

I am recording with Zoom H1. I have two ATR-3350 lav mics. They are self-powered and have 3.5 mm (1/8") mono miniplug. I would like to combine them into one stereo signal such that the left channel gets audio from mic 1 and the right channel gets audio from mic 2. I tried a basic Y combiner and it combines the two signals but not into separate left/right channels.

Comment: Although the other question refers to a computer as the destination, the actual problem is identical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a 2 mono to 1 stereo 3.5 adapter. (As it seems the input of the Zoom H1 is a 3.5 mm female jack). This is not a Y combiner.

That is a cable with 2 female mono 3.5 mm jack to 1 male stereo 3.5 jack.
For example : [image: adapter cable]

Comment: Where can I find one? I'd have thought monoprice.com, but I can't seem to find it there.