# What type of adapter combines 2 mono 3.5mm jacks into 1 stereo 3.5mm jack with each mono track on a different band?

Tags: terminology

[Note: Heavily edited for clarification]

My Zoom H1N can record stereo input from a 3.5mm input. I have two lav mics with 3.5mm ends. I want one mic to record into the left channel and the other to record into the right channel on my zoom. What kind of adapter/splitter do I need in order to do this?

There is a post [here](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/32987/combine-two-mono-mics-into-one-stereo-signal-such-that-each-mic-gets-its-own-ch/32988#32988?newreg=bc6466e771fb4baab44573f28ea3f912) with an adapter I think I need - but I don't know what it's called. It combines two mono 3.5mm inputs into one singular 3.5mm jack.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The linked question is 2 mono TR jack sockets to a stereo TRS plug. Is that not what you want? You can't send 2 TRS to 1 TRS without combining. In case you're struggling on terminology T=tip R=ring & S=sleeve, so plugs can go from TS right up to TRRRS, depending on how many channels they can carry.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification - I thought TRS was the same thing as any 3.5mm jack and it's not. I need two 3.5mm jacks to go into one single 3.5mm jack, but I need each Mono jack to be recorded separately into the Zoom H1n. Hope that make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought TRS was the same thing as any 3.5mm jack and it's not.

TRS is one of the possible configurations for a 3.5mm jack. TRS= Tip, Ring, Sleeve.

There are also TS (mono) and TRRS (stereo for headphones plus a microphone) 3.5 mm jacks.

> I need two 3.5mm jacks to go into one single 3.5mm jack, but I need each Mono jack to be recorded separately into the Zoom H1n.

That's the standard configuration. You need a 'dual mono 3.5 mm jack to stereo 3.5 mm jack' adapter.

They're available as a short cable (as shown in the linked question), or as an adapter plug:

[image]

They're also available with a female stereo socket and male mono plugs, but that's not what you need. You also don't want a splitter, because that will have 2x stereo female jacks instead of mono.

Answer (score 1):

It appears from a google search that this style of cable, one which splits the tip and ring to separate ends, is called a **”BREAKOUT”** cable

Answer (score -1):

3.5mm stereo jack to two mono left and right jack's are available on ebay. I was looking for the same thing and eventually found them and other variations on ebay